# How to replace username with link in string?

Tags: php

I'm trying to check posts to see whether they mention another user, by using @username. I want to replace that with a link to the user's profile.

This is what I've got... I haven't got any errors, but usernames just go through as text without the link. I feel like $getUsers/$gU isn't returning the results to $checkString, but I can't see anything wrong.

```
function post()
{
  global $me;

  if($_POST['message'])
  {
    $getUsers = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users");
    while($gU = mysql_fetch_array($getUsers))
    {
      $checkString = strpos($_POST['message'], "@".$gU['user_name']."");
      if($checkString !== false)
      {
        $replaceFrom = "@".$gU['user_name']."";
        $replaceTo = "<a href=\'/user.php?id=".$gU['user_id']."\'>".$gU['user_name']."</a>";
        $checked = str_replace($replaceFrom, $replaceTo, $_POST['message']);
      }
      else
      {
        $checked = $_POST['message'];
      }
    }
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('', '".$me['user_id']."', '".$_POST['topic']."', '".$checked."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
    index();
  }
  else {
    echo "
    <form action='?action=insert' method='post'>
    <input type=text name=topic maxlength=40>
    <br><textarea name=message cols=80 rows=9></textarea>
    <br><input type='submit' STYLE='color: black;  background-color: white;' value='Submit' class='btn'>
    </form>
    ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note the `mysql_` constructor has been **deprecated since 2013**, and is **removed in PHP 7**. This is because it has **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE IT**. If you're using a tutorial that uses it, find a better tutorial. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('', '".$me['user_id']."', '".$_POST['topic']."', '".$_POST['message']."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
```

should be

```
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('', '".$me['user_id']."', '".$_POST['topic']."', '".$checked."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
```

As your user table will eventually grow, I'd suggest compiling a set of potential usernames by searching for @(\w+), preparing a statement looking for that username, iterating through the results and replacing all instances for every returned row with the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have simplify your question by excluding the MySQL part. From what I understand you are trying to replace user mention with an HTML anchor tag.

Instead of looping through all the available users you can use `preg_replace_callback()` to check if any tagged user exists in system.

Please review the example code below. To simplify things I have created two functions. `parseTag()` will inject the HTML anchor link if the user exist, otherwise the original tag will be kept. `getUserId()` will return the user id it exists in the system instead:

```
<?php

function parseTag($tagInfo){
    list($fullTag, $username) = $tagInfo;

    $uid = getUserId($username);

    if  ($uid) {
        return "<a href='/url/to/user/{$uid}'>{$fullTag}</a>";
    }

    return $fullTag;

}

function getUserId($username){
    $userList = [null, 'john', 'mary'];

    return array_search($username, $userList);
}

$comment = "Hello @john, @doe does not exists";

$htmlComment = preg_replace_callback("/@([\w]+)/", "parseTag", $comment);

echo $htmlComment;
```

Output:

```
 Hello <a href='/url/to/user/1'>@john</a>, @doe does not exists
```

Comment: I reached a solution using preg_match after taking Frans's advice. Thanks for the alternative solution though :)